# Subsonic - let customers switch the database

Tags: subsonic

I am new to subsonic and I'd like to know about the best practices regarding the following scenario:

Subsonic supports multiple database systems, e.g. SQLServer and MySQL. Our customers need to decide while deploying our application to their servers, which database system should be used. Long story short: the providerName, normally specified within the application configuration, should be configurable after the application is finished.

How can this be done? Do I have to generate seperate data libraries for each database system I want to support?

Thank you in advance

Marco

Answer (score 1):

No you do not need to genarate seperate libraries.

How ever you can not use direct sql string as you understand but you need to go always using subsonic sql create code.

Also is good to make some tests on the diferent databases, because not all code have been 100% testes on every case.